# ZoneAwarePromise error on ionic 2 and angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I create hybrid apps with ionic 2 and angular 2, when on dev mode it can running fine on my android device , but when i compile for production i got Zone error like below

"Uncaught Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
I/chromium(16836): Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)"

From the error i think i must load zone.js after polyfill, but i cannot find how to make zone.js load after polyfill.

In which code part on ionic 2 that set the load order for zone.js and polyfill.js?